# What is username and password when starting Spring Boot with Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

When I deploy my Spring application via Spring Boot and access `localhost:8080` I have to authenticate, but what is the username and password or how can I set it?  I tried to add this to my `tomcat-users` file but it didn't work:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

This is the starting point of the application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

And this is the Tomcat dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

How do I authenticate on `localhost:8080`?

Comment: By setting up [spring-boot-starter-security](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/).

Comment: You need to authenticate = you want to have authentication? Because there is no authentication nor username & password in spring-boot-starter-tomcat/-web. If you see some, it's probably a different application on :8080

Comment: And it's printed on the console at launch.

Answer (score 383, accepted):

I think that you have Spring Security on your class path and then spring security is automatically configured with a default user and generated password

Please look into your pom.xml file for:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you have that in your pom than you should have a log console message like this:

`Using default security password: ce6c3d39-8f20-4a41-8e01-803166bb99b6`

And in the browser prompt you will import the user `user` and the password printed in the console.

Or if you want to configure spring security you can take a look at [Spring Boot secured example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-secure)

It is explained in the Spring Boot *Reference documentation* in the [Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security) section, it indicates:

```
The default AuthenticationManager has a single user (‘user’ username and random password, printed at `INFO` level when the application starts up)

Using default security password: 78fa095d-3f4c-48b1-ad50-e24c31d5cf35
```

Comment: If you fine tune your logging configuration, ensure that the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security` category is set to log INFO messages, otherwise the default password will not be printed.

Comment: beautiful. everything defaulted to something. double edged sword.

Comment: for my case (spring boot vs:2.0.4) console is "Using generated security password: eb7a9e02-b9cc-484d-9dec-a295b96d94ee"

Comment: This was just the case for me too.  I was just about to start asking question about it.

Comment: @Marcel I have added the spring security in class path, and can see the generated password, But when I use in basic auth via postman as username as user and password as generated password. I am getting unauthorised.

Comment: I am facing the same issue that @Lokesh Pandey is facing . I am using postman and used the generated password and username as user in basic authentication. but its not working.

Comment: @JassJava that's because of the spring security. I know why that issue is happening. I will recommend you to go through this incredible article which will give you enough insight on spring security https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-security

Comment: @LokeshPandey I understand that's because of Spring Security, also the automatically generated password which is being printed on console, I am using the same. Still postman says 401 UnAuthorized. Should I need to have my own username password implementation. I mean what if I do not want to do that, I only need to use the default password that spring generated. Simple as that it should have been, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: @JassJava that's the hashed password.

Comment: So which means there is no way I could decode this password and use it in postman.

Comment: The _Spring Boot secured example_ github project linked above does not exist anymore. It has been moved seemingly to [spring-projects/spring-security-samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples).

Answer (score 68):

If `spring-security` jars are added in classpath and also if it is `spring-boot` application all http endpoints will be secured by default security configuration class `SecurityAutoConfiguration`

This causes a browser pop-up to ask for credentials.

The password changes for each application restarts and can be found in console.

```
Using default security password: 78fa095d-3f4c-48b1-ad50-e24c31d5cf35
```

To add your own layer of application security in front of the defaults,

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

or if you just want to change password you could override default with,

**application.xml**

security.user.password=new_password

or

**application.properties**

```
spring.security.user.name=<>
spring.security.user.password=<>
```

Comment: i just added spring.security.user.name=<>
spring.security.user.password=<> to the application.properties file. I did not do anything else. Still it worked.

Comment: You have your property name wrong in the xml example
It's spring.security.user.password=xxx
Not sure about the XML formatting either as we use .yml files

Comment: When using the `inMemoryAuthentication` you rather prefix your password with {noop} when you receive the error: `There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id “null”`

Comment: add this in SecurityConfig class

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

It can fix There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id “null”

Answer (score 20):

When overriding

```
spring.security.user.name=
spring.security.user.password=
```

in **application.properties**, you don't need `"` around `"username"`, just use `username`. Another point, instead of storing *raw password*, encrypt it with **bcrypt/scrypt** and store it like

```
spring.security.user.password={bcrypt}encryptedPassword
```

Answer (score 5):

If you can't find the password based on other answers that point to a default one, the log message wording in recent versions changed to

```
Using generated security password: <some UUID>
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can also ask the user for the credentials and set them dynamically once the server starts (very effective when you need to publish the solution on a customer environment):**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        log.info("Setting in-memory security using the user input...");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputUser = null;
        String inputPassword = null;
        System.out.println("\nPlease set the admin credentials for this web application");
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("user: ");
            inputUser = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("password: ");
            inputPassword = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("confirm password: ");
            String inputPasswordConfirm = scanner.nextLine();

            if (inputUser.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Error: user must be set - please try again");
            } else if (inputPassword.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Error: password must be set - please try again");
            } else if (!inputPassword.equals(inputPasswordConfirm)) {
                System.out.println("Error: password and password confirm do not match - please try again");
            } else {
                log.info("Setting the in-memory security using the provided credentials...");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        scanner.close();

        if (inputUser != null && inputPassword != null) {
             auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(inputUser)
                .password(inputPassword)
                .roles("USER");
        }
    }
}
```

**(May 2018) An update - this will work on spring boot 2.x:**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Note: 
        // Use this to enable the tomcat basic authentication (tomcat popup rather than spring login page)
        // Note that the CSRf token is disabled for all requests
        log.info("Disabling CSRF, enabling basic authentication...");
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated() // These urls are allowed by any authenticated user
        .and()
            .httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        log.info("Setting in-memory security using the user input...");

        String username = null;
        String password = null;

        System.out.println("\nPlease set the admin credentials for this web application (will be required when browsing to the web application)");
        Console console = System.console();

        // Read the credentials from the user console: 
        // Note: 
        // Console supports password masking, but is not supported in IDEs such as eclipse; 
        // thus if in IDE (where console == null) use scanner instead:
        if (console == null) {
            // Use scanner:
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Username: ");
                username = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Password: ");
                password = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Confirm Password: ");
                String inputPasswordConfirm = scanner.nextLine();

                if (username.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Error: user must be set - please try again");
                } else if (password.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Error: password must be set - please try again");
                } else if (!password.equals(inputPasswordConfirm)) {
                    System.out.println("Error: password and password confirm do not match - please try again");
                } else {
                    log.info("Setting the in-memory security using the provided credentials...");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            scanner.close();
        } else {
            // Use Console
            while (true) {
                username = console.readLine("Username: ");
                char[] passwordChars = console.readPassword("Password: ");
                password = String.valueOf(passwordChars);
                char[] passwordConfirmChars = console.readPassword("Confirm Password: ");
                String passwordConfirm = String.valueOf(passwordConfirmChars);

                if (username.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Error: Username must be set - please try again");
                } else if (password.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Error: Password must be set - please try again");
                } else if (!password.equals(passwordConfirm)) {
                    System.out.println("Error: Password and Password Confirm do not match - please try again");
                } else {
                    log.info("Setting the in-memory security using the provided credentials...");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }

        // Set the inMemoryAuthentication object with the given credentials:
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder().encode(password);
            manager.createUser(User.withUsername(username).password(encodedPassword).roles("USER").build());
        }
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Addition to accepted answer -

If password not seen in logs, enable "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security" logs.

> If you fine-tune your logging configuration, ensure that the
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security category is set to log
>   INFO messages, otherwise the default password will not be printed.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security

Answer (score 1):

Ref- [Spring Boot 3 + Spring Security 6 Default username password generation in depth](https://www.javainuse.com/boot3/sec/3)
When we start the spring boot application which has spring security dependency
as follows-

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Then **UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration** creates a custom Spring Security User class with default username user and generated password. This Spring Security User class is then provided to InMemoryUserDetailsManager.
[image]
If the user creates its own UserDetailsService bean, then the UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration gets automatically disabled. In this case we pass the new created user to be used by the InMemoryUserDetailsManager.
With the new **Spring Boot 3 + Spring Security 6** configuration the code snippet for this is

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("javainuse").password("javainuse").authorities("read").build();
        userDetailsService.createUser(user);
        return userDetailsService;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring Security version 5.7.1, the default username is `user` and the password is randomly generated and displayed in the console (e.g. `8e557245-73e2-4286-969a-ff57fe326336`).

Please see the documentation for further details:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/getting-started.html

Answer (score -1):

When I started learning Spring Security, then I overrided the method **userDetailsService()** as in below code snippet:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        List<UserDetails> users= new ArrayList<UserDetails>();
        users.add(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("admin").password("nimda").roles("USER","ADMIN").build());
        users.add(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("Spring").password("Security").roles("USER").build());
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
    }
}
```

So we can log in to the application using the above-mentioned creds. (e.g. admin/nimda)

**Note: This we should not use in production.**

Answer (score -1):

Try to take username and password from below code snipet in your project and login and hope this will work.

```
@Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        List<UserDetails> users= new ArrayList<UserDetails>();
        users.add(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("admin").password("admin").roles("USER","ADMIN").build());
        users.add(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("spring").password("spring").roles("USER").build());
        return new UserDetailsManager(users);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

For a start simply add the following to your application.properties file

```
spring.security.user.name=user
spring.security.user.password=pass
```

NB: with no double quote

Run your application and enter the credentials (user, pass)