# Spring Security: How to change default user and password?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have Spring Security in my pom.xml, and Spring Security is automatically configured with a default user and generated password:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

How do I change the default user and password?

Comment: suppose this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285016/what-is-username-and-password-when-starting-spring-boot-with-tomcat) may be helpful and have a solution for what you are expecting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is username and password when starting Spring Boot with Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285016/what-is-username-and-password-when-starting-spring-boot-with-tomcat)

Answer (score 21):

This can be easly done in your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.security.user.name=user # Default user name.
spring.security.user.password= # Password
spring.security.user.roles=    # A comma separated list of roles
```

Covered at the [Common Application Properties - Security Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.security) documentation.

Comment: This is not working when using `Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE` and Security dependency, we need to implement `configure(...)` and extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Answer (score 8):

This is [straight from the docs](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/#websecurityconfigureradapter):

Create a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class HelloWebSecurityConfiguration
   extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth
      .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
  }
}
```

[Newer Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#hello-web-security-java-configuration)

This is slightly different, but the effect would be the same:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() throws Exception {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("user").password("password").roles("USER").build());
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Comment: JULY 03, 2013 old documentation :'(

Comment: I just did this with 1.5.6 successully.

Answer (score 7):

```
#add these lines in application.properties
    spring.security.user.name=username
    spring.security.user.password=password
```

Answer (score 2):

Ref-[Spring Boot 3 + Security - Change Default Password (Set Custom Credentials)](https://www.javainuse.com/boot3/sec/3)
With **Spring Boot 3 and Spring Security 6**, the configuration to have a custom username and password will be as follows-

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("javainuse").password("javainuse").authorities("read").build();
        userDetailsService.createUser(user);
        return userDetailsService;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below properties in `application.properties`

```
spring.security.user.name= user_name
spring.security.user.password= user_password
```

where "`user_name`" will be the user and "`user_password`" will be the password.

Answer (score 0):

These will not work with old version of spring boot, I was using 1.5.11.RELEASE and these properties were not working, After moving to 2.1.8.RELEASE, these properties work fine.

check your pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

spring.security.user.name=username
spring.security.user.password=password
```

Answer (score -1):

Set these 2 properties in your application.yml

```
spring.security.user.name=user_name
spring.security.user.password=user_password
```

**Now how does this work** 
 
If you search for `SecurityProperties.java` inside this class you will see that these 2 properties have default value as

```
String user = user;
String password = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Which are default credential for spring security
So we are basically override the default by setting those properties manually