# Swagger requesting credentials non of them is accepted

Tags: eclipse, swagger

I am receiving this pop up, http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html.
First i thought it is a password for my database or to my GIT. 
However non of the above is accepted.

[image]

```
package com.gabor.usermanagment.configs;


    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
    import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
    import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
    import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
    import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
    import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
    import static springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.regex;

    @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2
    public class SwaggerConfig {                                    
          @Bean
            public Docket productApi() {
                return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                        .select()
                        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.gabor.usermanagment.api"))
                        .paths(regex("/customerapi.*"))
                        .build()
                        .apiInfo(metaData());
            }
            private ApiInfo metaData() {
                ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                        "Spring Boot REST API",
                        "Spring Boot REST API for Online Store",
                        "1.0",
                        "Terms of service",
                        new Contact("John Thompson", "https://springframework.guru/about/", "john@springfrmework.guru"),
                       "Apache License Version 2.0",
                        "https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0");
                return apiInfo;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285016/what-is-username-and-password-when-starting-spring-boot-with-tomcat) really helped.

I had configured my app properly, but then I started to mess with packages. In my logs I could see something like this:

```
Using generated security password: 0768c114-ea85-4cd2-8cc0-626954b6557a
```

After I provided username: user and these generated password, openapi opened but there was no documentation.

I have few modules, and my core module with Application was in package: com.example.app.myapp

but my security and openapi configs were in package: com.example.app

So in my case there was problem with packages which was hidden behind security.

I hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score -2):

[What is username and password when starting Spring Boot with Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285016/what-is-username-and-password-when-starting-spring-boot-with-tomcat)

After going a little bit further with solutions, i have found it. This issue is resolved.