# I added port 8080 on ec2 security group but 8080 is not on listening list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

webpage is loading on localhost. but not with public IP. I get connection refused. so I checked port is listening but Its not. what can i do?

[Add 8080 port Inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LrwX.jpg)

```
[ec2-user@springboot-webservice ~]$ netstat -ntl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36145               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::43675                    :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN
```

Comment: Is you application even working on the instance? Can you verify that?

Comment: honestly, Im not sure. when I go on localhost:8080 I can go webpage and login. but not able to post..

Comment: When you mean "localhost", you mean on the ec2 instance itself? When you ssh into it, you can curl it `curl localhost:8080`?

Comment: when i curl localhost or hostname its refused as well

Comment: So you application is not running on the instance. You have to make it run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your application is running?
If not, then go to your application directory a un run it.
Gradle

**./gradlew bootRun**

Maven

**./mvnw spring-boot:run**

What port you specified for your application to run. If you don't specify any, by default it will run on port 8080.
You can add server.port in your application.properties to change your port if you prefer.

- src

  - main

    - resources

      - application.properties

#application.properties content

```
server.port=8080  #your port



#server.port=80  another port to test
```

If you have Spring Security in your dependencies, so that's  the reason for the login page.

Check [What is username and password when starting Spring Boot with Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285016/what-is-username-and-password-when-starting-spring-boot-with-tomcat)

If you only can see you application on localhost, but can't expose your application to the world.
Your EC2 instance is in a private subnet or a public subnet?
Your application can only be seen if it is on a public subnet. Default subnets are always public subnet.

Maybe this tutorial can help you check if any steps are missing. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2019/10/deploy-spring-boot-application-aws-ec2-instance.html