# Having error in loading localhost page while working with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, localhost, backend

I am a newbie to web development, and I have started to learn the backend. I chose Java in the backend, so I started learning spring boot. I used IntelliJ ide. When I ran my first code, I got connected to port 8080. But when I opened the localhost:8080 page in the web browser, it shows a sign-in page or some other pages. But in some tutorials I followed, they were able to modify the localhost:8080 page. And even tried to change the port, like 8090, it opens the same sign-in page. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmO3i.png)
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

I expected that the localhost page will open, and I will be able to modify that page by modifying the code. But wha[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nm0D.png)t actually happened was, i was not able to access the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is username and password when starting Spring Boot with Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285016/what-is-username-and-password-when-starting-spring-boot-with-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

When you start your application **password** got logged in console like this:

```
Using default security password: ce6c3d39-mf20-4w41-8e01-103166bb9nvc
```

And the username is **user**.
Thanks.

Comment: Should i use this crediential to login to localhost?

Comment: I did this, and it worked.