# Spring boot default user and password is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

As mentioned in this question:

- [What is username and password when starting Spring Boot with Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285016/what-is-username-and-password-when-starting-spring-boot-with-tomcat)

Default user name would be `user` and password will be printed on the termini if we use spring security.

#### pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.spring-projects</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-security</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Upon running the project, I got the below screen.
[image]

I tried to enter `user` as user name and `627719c9-c294-4d95-99af-96f2a92c8249` as password which was printed on the terminal.

[image]

I got the below screen, after clicking on Sign-In.
[image]

I also tried setting the default user name and password in the `application.properties` file, but it didn’t worked.

```
spring.security.user.name=rahul
spring.security.user.password=rahul
```

Comment: There is something else missing in your explanation since the Spring Security Sample using the default u/p is functional: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/hello-security - perhaps try comparing your application to that sample. Also, consider bumping your logs with logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE to give you more details about why Spring Security is rejecting the credentials. Post what more the logs tell you. Finally, please consider posting a GitHub sample that reproduces the issue so folks can take a closer look.

Comment: Please share your project so we can test it

Comment: FYI: it started working after system restart

Answer (score 0):

There is a minimal configuration required. Try to declare a class with this configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class ProjectSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        /**
         *  Below is the custom security configurations
         */

        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/myAccount","/myBalance","/myLoans","/myCards").authenticated()  
                .requestMatchers("/notices","/contact").permitAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
}
```

Comment: I am using java 17

Comment: `@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

 @Bean
 SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
  httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/account").authenticated().requestMatchers("/users")
    .permitAll().and().formLogin().and().httpBasic();
  return httpSecurity.build();
 }
}
`

Comment: The above configuration is also not working

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue on a freshly created spring boot project with spring security but then I tried with **postman with Basic authentication** and I was able to login with **both default user/password and custom one** from `application.poperties`.

Not sure why form-based login form  one was not working but postman was.