Update to Apereo CAS 7.0.5.1 from 6.6.6 does not load the custom html pages from src/main/resources/templates directory
I have upgaded my project Apereo CAS version from 6.6.6 to 7.0.5.1, application is up and running showing the message.
16.07.24 13:01:25.212 [main] [INFO] AbstractServicesManager.(): Loaded [15] service(s) from [ForceCasServiceRegistry,ForceOAuthServiceRegistry,JsonServiceRegistry].
16.07.24 13:01:25.221 [task-1] [INFO] CasWebApplicationReady.(): [36m
16.07.24 13:01:25.222 [task-1] [INFO] CasWebApplicationReady.(): 


 ____     ___   ____  ___    __ __ 
|    \   /  _] /    T|   \  |  T  T
|  D  ) /  [_ Y  o  ||    \ |  |  |
|    / Y    _]|     ||  D  Y|  ~  |
|    \ |   [_ |  _  ||     |l___, |
|  .  Y|     T|  |  ||     ||     !
l__j\_jl_____jl__j__jl_____jl____/ 
                                   
CAS is now running at https://fcnb0047:25443/auth

16.07.24 13:01:25.222 [task-1] [INFO] CasWebApplicationReady.(): [0m
16.07.24 13:01:25.222 [task-1] [INFO] CasWebApplicationReady.(): Ready to process requests @ [2024-07-16T11:01:25.131Z]


but when I hit the application url from the browser then I cannot see the expected login pages which I have defined at the src/main/resources/templates/login/casLoginView.html.
I see something very different on the screen which as :

I have already double checked the location of the custom pages and matched it to the expected location according to the documentation. https://apereo.github.io/cas/7.0.x/ux/User-Interface-Customization-Views.html
Removed my custom pages(Just to test) and expected that the default screen of CAS Apereo I should see that is also not visible.
Tried and serached search engine for answers but I cannot understand from where this dialogue is rendered.
I expect that if I have not defined any custom pages then I should see the CAS default login page rendered otherwise I should see my custom pages.

I noticed that if I have the spring.properties in my src/main/resources with a property (spring.index.ignore=true) defined in it, then I see this pop-up box in my browser, if I make this property false or remove it completely then I run into bean undefined issues.

This was eventually found to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46606542/3203794 and fixed after I have configured SecurityFilterChain correctly in my code.
